# Probability problem of flipping coin, roll dice and roulette wheel

Tags: discrete-mathematics

An experiment consists of flipping a coin, rolling a 11 sided die, and spinning a roulette wheel. What is the probability that the coin comes up heads and the die comes up less than 4 and the roulette wheel comes up with a number greater than 14 ?

---

My thought process was to break down each instance separately and then multiply them all together but not sure if i am going about the problem the right way

coin flip:
$\frac{1}{2}$

rolling a 11 sided dice come up less than 4:
$\frac{3}{11}$

roulette wheel come up greater than 14:
$\frac{15}{36}$

Comment: Yes, you are thinking about this the right way: since these events are independent, you can just multiply their individual probabilities to get the probability for all three to happen at once.  One question remains: does the roulette wheel have a $0$, or maybe even a $00$?

Comment: Is the coin fair?  Is the die fair?  How does a roulette wheel work (i.e. how many possible outcomes are there?)?  Are all of the events independent?

Comment: @Bram28 good point not sure

Comment: @Bram28 A roulette wheel has [both](https://www.palaceofchance.com/ask/common-questions/what-do-the-0-and-00-on-the-roulette-machine-mean-5567/) $0$ and $00$.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Depends on the roulette wheel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette